# three.js vertex shader: update attributes and how to save a value for the next processing round

Tags: javascript, glsl, three.js, webgl

Here is a gist of a very simple setup: https://gist.github.com/ichbinadrian/4758155

My basic plan is to color the fragments in relation to the distance they have to the lowest or highest vertex. Like a mountain range. How can I save a value in the shader which I can use for later rounds of processing. Because the vertices will change position over time.

At least that is the plan. Because I can't figure out how to update the vertices and faces after I changed the values in attributes. It worked well when I changed the vertices position outside the shader and set xNeedUpdate = true.

Shaders logic are not that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this in your render loop:

```
attributes.displacement.needsUpdate = true;
```

your gist will work.

Comment: Holy… as easy as it gets. Thanks.